# How to share text in IOS using UIActivityViewController in Kotlin

Tags: ios, swift, kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform, mobile-development

I'm trying to get more familiar with KMP (Kotlin Multiplatform)
so I'm trying to call an old API from iOS in kotlin in the iOS module

```kotlin
fun shareText(text: String, subject: String) {
        val activityController = UIActivityViewController(
            activityItems = listOf(text),
            applicationActivities = null,
        )
        val window = UIApplication.sharedApplication.windows().first() as UIWindow?
        activityController.popoverPresentationController()?.sourceView =
            window
        activityController.setTitle(subject)
        window?.rootViewController?.presentViewController(
            activityController as UIViewController,
            animated = true,
            completion = null,
        )
    }
```

And the implementation seems to be working

[image: Simulator image]

However as soon I close the sheet dialog I get message in the log

```
[ShareSheet] connection invalidated
```

Why some properties names different in kotlin than swift??

the code

```swift
UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.rootViewController?.present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

is

```kotlin
(UIApplication.sharedApplication.windows().first() as UIWindow?)?.rootViewController?.presentViewController(
            activityController as UIViewController,
            animated = true,
            completion = null,
        )
```

We still can't call swift code in our project from Kotlin directly

the way I did it seems to be unsafe, is there a better way to do this??

Thank you for your efforts.

Comment: "the way I did it seems to be unsafe" Why do you think that?

Comment: That said, why are you presenting it from the root VC? Do you not have access to a `UIViewController`?

Comment: I do but the casting and everything doesn't seems efficient code

Comment: Casting isn’t inefficient. It’s just a type check. Sure, it might looks ugly to some people, but I think you should blame Objective-C for that.

Comment: Blame Objective-C for that?? I'm sure you've heard of Java before, the issue with the type technically could be anything and cause a cast exception to be thrown

Comment: I’m not sure why Java is relevant. The reason why you need to cast is because Kotlin doesn’t understand that `windows` is an array of `UIWindow`. A cast exception will *not* be thrown.

Comment: Please do not add new questions to your post. You should not ask multiple questions un one post. You might want to post a new question instead.

Comment: It's related to the same topic and I'm sure many Kotlin developers might find this helpful

Answer (score -1):

sharing text using `UIActivityViewController` in Swift. using Swift code in a Kotlin `context`, which won't work as-is. Here's the equivalent code for sharing text in iOS using `UIActivityViewController` in Kotlin:

```
        import platform.UIKit.*

        fun shareText(text: String, subject: String, viewController: UIViewController) {
            val activityController = UIActivityViewController(
                activityItems = listOf(text),
                applicationActivities = null
            )

            activityController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = viewController.view
            activityController.setTitle(subject)

            viewController.presentViewController(activityController, animated = true, completion = null)
        }
```

Comment: Thanks, the context is Android spesefic (that is if you mean context from Android) and here we are in the iOS module, if we are in Compose multiplatform what is the right way to get the viewController instance??